# The save settings code does not work in a project vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a project with text boxes
And I have a command button to change the font type, color and size
I want the correct way in code to save these settings after exiting the program
Even if I open the project again, it will still be the same font type and color as the one in the text boxes
Thanks to all

This is a picture of the font and color settings [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vXbQ.png)

```
Private Sub MyLibrary_FormClosed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    My.Settings.Text_Color = TxtBook.ForeColor
    My.Settings.Text_Font = TxtBook.Font
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
Private Sub Text_Font()
TxtBook.Font = My.Settings.Text_Font
    TxtAuthor.Font = My.Settings.Text_Font
    TxtPublisher.Font = My.Settings.Text_Font
    TxtPublish.Font = My.Settings.Text_Font
    txtPage.Font = My.Settings.Text_Font
    TxtNote.Font = My.Settings.Text_Font
 TxtBook.ForeColor = My.Settings.Text_Color
    TxtAuthor.ForeColor = My.Settings.Text_Color
    TxtPublisher.ForeColor = My.Settings.Text_Color
    TxtPublish.ForeColor = My.Settings.Text_Color
    txtPage.ForeColor = My.Settings.Text_Color
    TxtNote.ForeColor = My.Settings.Text_Color
End Sub
```

Comment: **Hint:** The `Text_Font` method gets the saved properties and not setting them. And where does `Me.setting` come from? Is it `My.Settings`? Or another instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have makes little sense as it is. This is why you need to have a clear understanding of the logic you're trying to implement before writing code. You can then compare the code to the logic whenever things don't work as expected. Let's step through the code you have.

When the form is closed, you do this:

```vb
Text_Font()
```

In that method, you do this:

```vb
Me.TxtBook.Font = Me.setting.Text_Font
'...
Me.TxtBook.ForeColor = Me.setting.Text_Color
'...
```

You're modifying that control based on the current value of the settings. You then do this:

```vb
Me.setting.Text_Color = TxtBook.ForeColor
Me.setting.Text_Font = TxtBook.Font
```

You're updating the settings with the values from the control... which you just got from the settings! How does that make sense? You haven't shown us anywhere else in your code that you're changing either the settings or the controls, so how is anything actually supposed to change?

I would think that the logical thing to do would be to update the settings somewhere when the user chooses to. How you do that is up to you. The user chooses the font and/or colour and you update the settings and then update the controls from the setting. You can save the settings when you set them, by explicitly calling `Save`, or you can just let the application save them automatically at shutdown, which is the default behaviour.

Actually I just realised that you're using `Me.setting` everywhere rather than `My.Settings`. I don;t know whether that's a typo but, if you expect to modify standard application settings then you need to use `My.Settings`, e.g.

```vb
Me.TxtBook.Font = My.Settings.Text_Font
```

Overall, you might consider something like this:

```vb
Private Sub UpdateFontSettings()
    'Update My.Settings values here.

    My.Settings.Save()

    UpdateControlFonts()
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateControlFonts()
    'Update control properties from settings here.
End Sub
```

When the form loads, you would call `UpdateControlFonts`. When the user makes changes, you would call `UpdateFontSettings`. At shutdown, you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Sorry, sir
I forgot to tell you that I am a beginner in visual field

Comment: Thank you for your effort in responding
I was able to modify and correct the code thanks to your instructions
I am grateful and indebted to you